# Intellij IDEA Latest version(ideaIU-2021.2.2 ) keep crashing in MacOS

Tags: intellij-idea, macos-big-sur

I am trying to update or reinstall latest version of IDEA from 2020.3 to 2021.2.2 which is keep crashing in MacOS. I tried to uninstall and delete all existing folders like cache, logs etc but still same issue. Please help!

Below is the MacOS reporting stack trace:

> Process:               idea [46282] Path:
> /private/var/folders/*/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea
> Identifier:            com.jetbrains.intellij Version:
> 2021.2.2 (IU-212.5284.40) Code Type:             X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        ??? [1] Responsible:           idea [46282]
> User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2021-09-20 16:40:06.524 +0530 OS Version:
> macOS 11.6 (20G165) Report Version:        12 Bridge OS Version:
> 5.5 (18P4759a) Anonymous UUID:        434C2C7D-709A-E6A0-CE1E-44E6AABE6D87
>
> Sleep/Wake UUID:       4A9CC604-3A7A-4339-B3FC-7C519F79F4C0
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 85000 seconds Time Since Wake:       20000
> seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Notes:                 Translocated Process
>
> Crashed Thread:        3
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
> KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
> EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> ### VM Regions Near 0:
>
> ```
> __TEXT                      109749000-109751000    [   32K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /var/folders/*/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea
> ```
>
> Application Specific Information: abort() called
>
> Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
> libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff204ff2ba mach_msg_trap + 10 1
> libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff204ff62c mach_msg + 60 2
> com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff2062c49f
> __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316 3   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff2062ab7f __CFRunLoopRun + 1328 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation
> 0x00007fff20629f8c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563 5
> com.jetbrains.intellij            0x000000010974d9e3 main + 332 6
> libdyld.dylib                     0x00007fff2054ff3d start + 1
>
> Thread 1: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20530420
> start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 2: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20530420
> start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 3 Crashed: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
> 0x00007fff2050592e __pthread_kill + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib
> 0x00007fff205345bd pthread_kill + 263 2   libsystem_c.dylib
> 0x00007fff20489406 abort + 125 3   libjvm.dylib
> 0x000000010bcc33a0 os::abort(bool, void*, void const*) + 22 4
> libjvm.dylib                      0x000000010ba907f6 jni_FatalError + 244
> 5   libjvm.dylib                      0x000000010bb7794d
> JvmtiExport::post_vm_initialized() + 393 6   libjvm.dylib
> 0x000000010bdc4cea Threads::create_vm(JavaVMInitArgs*, bool*) + 1844
> 7   libjvm.dylib                      0x000000010baaa2a0 JNI_CreateJavaVM
>
> - 96 8   com.jetbrains.intellij           0x000000010974f7a8 -[Launcher launch] + 371 9   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff213b4437
>   **NSThread__start** + 1068 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fff205348fc _pthread_start + 224 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x00007fff20530443 thread_start + 15
>
> ......
>
> Thread 3 last branch register state not available.
>
> Binary Images:
> 0x109749000 -        0x109750fff +com.jetbrains.intellij (2021.2.2 - IU-212.5284.40) <305B2794-5B9E-3DE9-B3ED-02140CF70AC2>
> /var/folders/*/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea
> 0x10b690000 -        0x10b69afff +net.java.openjdk.11.0.12.jdk (1.0 - 11.0.12) <792B647E-6262-3390-A4F1-225DA7483FC1>
> /var/folders/*/IntelliJ
> IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib
> 0x10b6a5000 -        0x10bee8fff +libjvm.dylib (0) <17796A43-93D9-37A3-A25C-76C394E271F0> /var/folders/*/IntelliJ
> IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
> 0x10c3fd000 -        0x10c404fff +libverify.dylib (0)  /var/folders/*/IntelliJ
> IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/lib/libverify.dylib
> 0x10c40e000 -        0x10c424fff +libjava.dylib (0)  /var/folders/*/IntelliJ
> IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/lib/libjava.dylib
> 0x10c43a000 -        0x10c43cfff +libjimage.dylib (0) <32BBAD48-8E93-36F7-91EB-CA655358E61B> /var/folders/*/IntelliJ
> IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/lib/libjimage.dylib
> 0x10c448000 -        0x10c44efff +libinstrument.dylib (0)  /var/folders/*/IntelliJ
> IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/lib/libinstrument.dylib
> 0x10c460000 -        0x10c464fff +libzip.dylib (0) <1612977E-7B76-3B4C-A588-7C550EE6276D> /var/folders/*/IntelliJ
> IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/lib/libzip.dylib
> 0x114671000 -        0x114677fff +libnio.dylib (0) <6EEB2F83-9F79-3DB6-81D1-71FA1AA15E69> /var/folders/*/IntelliJ
> IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/lib/libnio.dylib
> 0x114684000 -        0x114690fff +libnet.dylib (0)  /var/folders/*/IntelliJ
> IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/lib/libnet.dylib
> 0x1147f0000 -        0x11480afff +libsunec.dylib (0) <9D5CB4FE-D40D-368F-87C6-302BCBFFA916> /var/folders/*/IntelliJ
> IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/lib/libsunec.dylib
> 0x115b15000 -        0x115bb0fff  dyld (852.2) <0CC19410-FD43-39AE-A32A-50273F8303A4> /usr/lib/dyld
> ....
>
> External Modification Summary:   Calls made by other processes
> targeting this process:
> task_for_pid: 0
> thread_create: 0
> thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by this process:
> task_for_pid: 0
> thread_create: 0
> thread_set_state: 0   Calls made by all processes on this machine:
> task_for_pid: 0
> thread_create: 0
> thread_set_state: 0
>
> VM Region Summary: ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=682.6M
> resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=682.6M(100%) Writable
> regions: Total=838.7M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%)
> swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=838.7M(100%)

Comment: Please try to add the following VM options(https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869):

-XX:+TieredCompilation
-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1

Comment: I am not able to update this file and add JVM args.

Comment: Could you please clarify?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, were you able to fix it?
My IntelliJ is crashing as soon as I start

Comment: I fixed it by downloading 2020 version or upgrade to latest version that is 2021.3 . I have also upgraded my MacOS version to 12.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by downgrading Intellij version to  2020 version. I have also upgraded my MacOS version to latest that is 12.0.1